# search block form not accepting special characters in drupal 7

Tags: forms, search

If I search with any special character in drupal default search block form it returns error message like "You must include at least one positive keyword with characters or more.".after i do search with letters or numbers it does not bring results.shows same error.the form has been submitted but value does not change.
Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with special characters (e.g. "$", "@"). It pertains to the **length of your keywords**. By default, Drupal core search restricts minimum keyword size to 3; any query less than 3 characters will trigger the error (e.g. "$9").

If you really need search to include 2/1 character queries, the search settings in **/admin/config/search/settings** under the **Minimum word length to index** option will allow you to do this.

**Note:** This will expand out the size of your search index (catching common words like "an" & "a"). If you have a large site with thousands of nodes you shouldn't do this.